# Is it possible to build an Excel RTD Server that runs on MacOS using C# and .NET Core?

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, cross-platform, rtd

I want to buid an RTD Server that provides users with some market data. After some research I've learn that I can achieve that in Windows and .NET by [implementing the IRtdServer interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.irtdserver?view=excel-pia) located in the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace.

However things seem to be more difficult when it comes to a cross platform implementation things seem to get more challenging, [as you can see on this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/rtd-server-on-office-for-mac/725cf150-5181-40dc-a41c-842ba4438900) on the MS Office forum.

The answer by Bob Greenblatt says:

> So, you want the data pushed to excel, correct? As far as I know that
> is not possible in Mac excel. If it is actually a stock price you are
> looking for, you can use a web query refreshed by VBA. However, VBA
> will need to be in control to trigger the query refresh.

The accepted answer says:

> Sounds like you could set the RTD up as a web service, which Excel can
> consume using web queries, as described by Bob.
>
> The RTD itself could also be Excel. There is a little used and
> practically unknown feature in Excel for Mac where you can set Excel
> up to build a dynamic web page. In File > Save As choose format Single
> File Web Page (.mht) and in the Save As dialog click the Automate
> button that lets you set a schedule for when the web site
> automatically updates, the idea being that the saved .mht file resides
> on a web server that is accessible to your consuming Excel clients via
> a web query. [...]

However VB isn't an option for me, as I'm building a cross platform Xamarin.Forms application that runs in both Windows and MacOS. Hence why I need to support RTD for both Excel for Windows and Excel for Mac.

Does anyone know if a C# and .NET Standard implementation of a RTD Server is possible?

Answer (score 3):

RTD uses COM (common object model), a Microsoft proprietary system (from long ago, 1980's/1990's), to communicate between Excel and an RTD server.  MAC does not have and understanding of COM, so it would not be possible for Excel on a MAC, to use RTD.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.